# Grouping Dataframe rows based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe which has such columns: Phase, Approach, info 1, info 2. I want a specific kind of grouping based on two conditions, but i don't know if groupby will help me or another method is needed.
Here's the conditions:

1. Rows which have the same Phase and Approach, must be considered a group.
2. Rows which don't have the same Phase but have the exact Approach, info1 and info2, must be considered a group too.

Here's an example:

|  | Phase | Approach | info1 | info2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A1 | EB | J | K |
| 1 | A1 | EB | N | V |
| 2 | A1 | WB | L | M |
| 3 | A2 | WB | L | M |
| 4 | A2 | EB | L | M |
| 5 | A3 | EB | L | M |
| 6 | A3 | WB | S | H |
| 7 | B | NB | T | K |
| 8 | B | NB | K | T |

Based on conditions above, the groups would be as such:

- 0 and 1 (Because of the same Phase and Approach)
- 2 and 3 (Because of the same Approach and info1 and info2)
- 4 and 5 (Because of the same Approach and info1 and info2)
- 6       (None of the conditions are met)
- 7 and 8 (Because of the same Phase and Approach)

How can I implement that?

I've tried the code below but it would imply the conditions separately on the dataframe. But I want them to work at the same time, so i'm not sure if .groupby() would be a solution for it or not.

```
import pandas as pd


# Grouping based on the first condition
grouped_condition1 = df.groupby(['Phase', 'Approach'])

# Grouping based on the second condition
# First, we create a new column to store the combined key of Approach, info1, and info2
df['CombinedKey'] = df['Approach'] + df['info1'] + df['info2']

# Next, we use groupby along with transform to assign a common label for rows that share the same CombinedKey
grouped_condition2 = df.groupby('CombinedKey')

# Now you have two different groupings based on your conditions.
```

Comment: Hi Mahtab, welcome! I suppose you could make some kind of grouping column (e.g. group by phase and approach, then create a column where if the number of rows in a group is larger than one, then the value is [phase, approach], otherwise it is [approach, info1, info2]. Then group by this new column

Comment: I think it's possible for there to be three records 0, 1, 2 for which, using these rules, 0 would group with 1, and 1 with 2 but 0 does not group with 2. e.g. (phase, approach, info1, info2) are 0:(0,0,0,0) 1:(0,0,1,1), 2:(1,0,1,1). In cases like these do you want to combine all three records to a single group?

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code) or [table formatting](/editing-help#tables). For related tips, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). BTW, check out [ask] for more tips, like how to write a good title.

Comment: @DavidHarris Hi, thanks, but I didn't completely understand. What happens for other rows?

Comment: @Mark Hi hi thanks:D And thanks a lot for your answer, that's a very good idea. I'm gonna try it.

Comment: In @David's example, other rows don't matter; he's only asking about the three he mentioned. Another way to say it is, which rows should be grouped in that case? Although, your example data doesn't have this problem, so maybe your real-world data doesn't either.

Comment: Did Mark's idea end up working? I'm trying to work through this myself now using only groupby, but the problem is it doesn't work like that; it groups by value, not by finding matches; that is, for example, row 3's Phase and Approach are in a group of 1, or, in a sense, it has the same Phase and Approach as *itself*.

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but for `grouped_condition2`, the comment says you're using `.transform()`, but you're not. And you don't need to make `CombinedKey` when you can group by multiple columns like the first case: `df.groupby(['Approach', 'info1', 'info2'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Groupby doesn't work by finding matches, it works by **value**, that is, for example, row 3's Phase and Approach make a group of size 1, or, in a sense, it has the same Phase and Approach as *itself*.

But, if we rework the conditions to require groups of size >1, we can definitely use groupby to do the heavy lifting. We can use `.transform()` to check the sizes, then null out non-matching values so that they're ignored.

#### Getting group keys

##### Condition 1

Checking for matches

```
keys1 = ['Phase', 'Approach']
mask1 = df.groupby(keys1).transform('size').ne(1)
```

So the group keys will be:

```
cond1 = df.loc[mask1, keys1]
```

```
  Phase Approach
0    A1       EB
1    A1       EB
7     B       NB
8     B       NB
```

##### Condition 2

```
keys2 = ['Approach', 'info1', 'info2']
mask2 = df[~mask1].groupby(keys2).transform('size').ne(1)
cond2 = df.loc[~mask1 & mask2, keys2]
```

```
  Approach info1 info2
2       WB     L     M
3       WB     L     M
4       EB     L     M
5       EB     L     M
```

##### Combine

```
group_keys = pd.concat([cond1, cond2])
```

```
>>> group_keys.sort_index()
  Phase Approach info1 info2
0    A1       EB   NaN   NaN
1    A1       EB   NaN   NaN
2   NaN       WB     L     M
3   NaN       WB     L     M
4   NaN       EB     L     M
5   NaN       EB     L     M
7     B       NB   NaN   NaN
8     B       NB   NaN   NaN
```

(note that row 6 is missing)

#### Grouping

`df.groupby(group_keys)` doesn't work, saying `ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional`. I'm not sure why, but I'll get back to you if I find a solution.

As a workaround:

```
groups = df.groupby(group_keys.apply(tuple, axis=1), sort=False)
```

Showing the result:

```
>>> groups.apply(lambda x: x[:])
                     Phase Approach info1 info2
(A1, EB, nan, nan) 0    A1       EB     J     K
                   1    A1       EB     N     V
(nan, WB, L, M)    2    A1       WB     L     M
                   3    A2       WB     L     M
(nan, EB, L, M)    4    A2       EB     L     M
                   5    A3       EB     L     M
(B, NB, nan, nan)  7     B       NB     T     K
                   8     B       NB     K     T
```